# Strange offset with mesh boolean in Geometry Nodes

Tags: geometry-nodes

I'm trying to create a procedural plane with many small holes in it. I want to use geometry nodes for this for some downstream applications.

I have an input plane. I distribute points on the plane and instance small cylinders, whose dimensions are adjusted slightly using a noise texture. Then I realize instances and apply a mesh boolean to cut the holes. Should be pretty simple.

However, I'm getting this strange offset behavior where not all the holes are cut out properly. I've tried with self intersection and hole tolerant on. I've also tried giving the plane some thickness before the boolean, and subdividing the mesh to give some more geometry.

[image: Hole Tolerant Off]

[image: Hole Tolerant On]

[image: With Thickness]

Any ideas why this is happening? Any better strategies for doing this with geo nodes?

[image]

Comment: Can you share the file? https://blend-exchange.com/

Comment: Sorry about that, blend file uploaded

Comment: Even with the simplest setup (plugging the `Cylinder` directly into the `Mesh Boolean`) the problem persists. If you increase the `Depth` in the `Cylinder` node gradually, you can see how the problematic cuts move away. Seems to be a precision problem of the `Mesh Boolean` as you need more depth when scaling up the plane.

Comment: @taiyo yeah oops i answered without reading the comments that you already found out. looks like a bug.

Comment: @HarryMcKenzie no worries.

Comment: @HarryMcKenzie I think with the regular _Boolean_ modifier there are always options to try to get a better result like the _Solver_ settings _Fast_ and _Exact_ or the options like _Self Intersection_ or _Hole Tolerant_. It's unfortunate that these things are not available in the _Mesh Booelan_ node, maybe this would have helped here. Perhaps they will be added one day.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is a very strange issue looks more like a bug. To fix it just increase the Cylinder node's *Depth* from 0.5 to 1 or any higher value.

I noticed @[taiyo](https://blender.stackexchange.com/users/161172/taiyo) has already pointed this issue out:

> Even with the simplest setup (plugging the Cylinder directly into the
> Mesh Boolean) the problem persists. If you increase the *Depth* in the
> Cylinder node gradually, you can see how the problematic cuts move
> away. Seems to be a precision problem of the Mesh Boolean as you need
> more depth when scaling up the plane

[image]

Comment: I noticed that Blender recalculates the plane's z-Dimension (non-zero and without changing the z-Scale) when changing the cylinder depth. If the depth value jumps across a certain big enough value, the z-Dimension snaps to zero. At that moment, the erroneous cuts should be gone. Changing the z-Dimension directly does not help, as the plane's scale is also adjusted, this just scales the weird cuts. Thus the advice to raise the depth still holds, but it can be added "until the z-Dimension value snaps to zero" (if the plane is rotated somehow, the snapping still occures with a non-zero value).

Comment: Thanks all! Strange behavior but appreciate the insight.